# How to force a PC boot from CD the next time it restarts?

Tags: windows-xp, boot

Starting in a normal installation of Windows XP - is there some way to specify when the machine next restarts, it should boot from the CD (e.g. into BartPE)? And then the next restart, the machine boots into Windows as normal?

I'm looking to do this remotely without anyone touching the machine or keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

no, you can't.

you can have the machine booting either form HDD or CDROM first, but you will have to make the changes manually in the BIOS.

as for 'remotely', you can use a [KVM over IP](http://www.kvms.com/Landing/IP-KVM-Central.aspx) extender with BIOS level acces, but they don't come cheap and it still is not an automated process.

Answer (score 2):

This has to be done through the BIOS or via a boot options key (used to quickly change boot options without entering BIOS). Either way, it's long before the GUI is loaded, so doing it remotely won't work unless you're using [KVM over IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#KVM_over_IP).